# Best practice to place menu Icons on the left side of the navigation drawer in Persian,Hebrew devices?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, right-to-left, left-to-right

I am trying to have a navigation drawer that opens from the right. ( i managed to do that using LAYOUT_GRAVITY="END").
Now I want all the menu items to start from the right and also their Icons on the right too.

[image]

To do that I added (SUPPORTSRTL="TRUE") to the manifest and that also solved the problem. But here is the problem:

- if the device's language is set to English, everything works perfectly.
- But if the device's language is set to Persian(which is a RTL language) then everything else in the app will be right to left. That means what ever I put in the right goes to left and what ever that is set to the left goes to the right. I even tried using "start" and "end" instead of "right" and "left" but that didn't solve the problem.

To solve that I had to set the (LAYOUTDIRECTION="LTR") to the root element of layouts on every one of my actitives. That solved the problem and now everything is in the position I desired, however this doesn't seem like a sustainable solution to add this line of code to root element of each activity I will ever add to my app.
Can you please tell me if this is the best way to do it or not?

I found other questions with the same topic with no accepted proper answers.

Comment: I have no idea why the image is so big, I couldn't find a way to make it smaller. it's not that big in my computer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line of code should solve your problem

```
    ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(drawer, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

drawer is a reference to your DrawerLayout.

an other way to force RTL layout to activities is using styles xml. this is how i whould do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="ShaliRTL" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

then in android manifest apply this new style (ShaliRTL) to your specific activity:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/ShaliRTL"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" />
```

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response. I will try your first solution once I get access to my computer and get back to you if it works or not. but the second method to use style would definitely do the job instead of setting it manually for each layout. Thanks!